# Laravel Jetstream components

Tags: components, customization, laravel-8, laravel-jetstream

Despite some research, I could not find any reference to how to customise Jetstream components such as 'welcome'. Maybe someone has a hint how to do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

Try this:

```
php artisan vendor:publish --tag=jetstream-views
```

After that files will be available under the folder `resources/views/vendor/jetstream/components`

In this directory you will be able to find this `welcome.blade.php`

Answer (score 2):

it  easy to customize use

```
php artisan vendor:publish --tag=jetstream-views
```

to publish Components

go to `resources/views/welcome.blade.php`

edit and modify the blade file to suit your customization

Answer (score 1):

If you want to create a custom [Laravel Jetstream](https://jetstream.laravel.com/) [Blade component](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/blade#components) for example `my-component` or override a predefined one, there are steps:

1. Create a Blade HTML template at, for example, `resources/views/components/my-component.blade.php`
2. Edit the `boot()` method of `JetstreamServiceProvider` class at `app/Providers/JetstreamServiceProvider.php`

and add the code:

```
public function boot()
{
    //existing code....
    
    $this->callAfterResolving(BladeCompiler::class, function () {
        Blade::component('components.my-component', 'jet-my-component');
    });
}
```